# Out of Memory Exception when loading large number of images through a file picker

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, windows-phone-8.1

Windows Phone 8.1:

```
foreach (StorageFile file in ImageFiles)
            {

                ClassForFolderImages CFFI = new ClassForFolderImages();
                using(var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                 var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

                 bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 80;
                 bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 80;
                 await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);

                 CFFI.imageForFolder = bitmapImage;

                 GridViewName.Add(CFFI);
                }
            }
```

in the above snippet "ImageFiles" contains a large number of Images and "GridViewName" is the name of the observable collection which I later bind to a grid view where I wish to display these Images.
The ClassForFolderImages Class is as below:

```
public class ClassForFolderImages : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private BitmapImage img;

    public BitmapImage imageForFolder
    {
        get { return img; }

        set
        {
            img = value;
            FirePropertyChangedEvent("imageForFolder");
        }
    }


    public ClassForFolderImages()
    {

    }

    private void FirePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }

}
```

This Snippet works fine in the phone simulator and for small number of images on the device ,but on the device - as the number of images increase at some point it starts throwing the below error (it breaks at App.g.i.cs) :

```
Exception = The function evaluation was disabled because of an out of memory exception.
Handled = The function evaluation was disabled because of an out of memory exception.
Message = The function evaluation was disabled because of an out of memory exception.
```

Can anyone suggest changes to overcome this problem?

Comment: Are you disposing the streams when you are done?

Comment: Tried that. didn't work.

Comment: As well as actually cleaning up your images by disposing the streams, I suggest streaming in only the images that are actually in view, with a reasonable buffer upwards and downwards.

Comment: Agree with J.Steen. Paging is your way to go.

Comment: Can't go for that. need all the images at once.

Comment: Going by your tags it looks like a phone application and I would assume even a tablet has limit to how many recognizable decent quality images it can display at once.

Comment: have a function to select all the images at once. Not sure if paging will let me do that.

Comment: yes its an application for windows phone 8.1

Comment: have you tried call manually the garbage collector?

Comment: yes tried it once before but didn't help.

Comment: How many images are we talking about? 20? 50? 100? More? Have you tried using the Memory Profiler of VS to see what's consuming the memory?

Comment: Works fine for around 95 images. Error pops up after that. Haven't tried Memory profiler yet.

Comment: I see. Well, the best thing you can do is what J. Steen suggested. It is actually the only thing that will truly solve the problem. I'm pretty sure you can make the Select All work one way or another.